# continue program in c++

Tags: c++

my program is

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        int exit;
        while(1==1)
        {
                float a,b,c;
                printf("Enter length(in metre)");
                scanf("%f",&a);
                printf("Enter width(in metre)");
                scanf("%f",&b);
                printf("Enter height(in metre)");
                scanf("%f",&c);
                if(5.919<a<=12.056 && 2.340<b<=2.347 && 2.380<c<=2.648)
                {
                        printf("40' high cube \n");
                }
                else if(a<=5.662 && 2.340<b<=2.438 && c<=2.16)
                {
                        printf("20' open top");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("40' flat rack");
                }
                cout << "Would you like to exit?(Yes/No)"<<endl;
                cin >> exit;
                if(exit == 1)
                {
                        break;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

But, the code is given wrong asnwers.No matter whatever feed i give..it is selecting 40" high cube
Also,I want to input yes/no to continue,instead of 1. How should I do it?

Comment: Mixing scanf and cin is the path to the dark side, or exactly this kind of headache.

Comment: `5.919<a<=12.056` doesn't work like you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For input yes/no, You can use this  way..

```
char exit;
```

// in while loop waiting for user input

```
exit = getch();
if(exit == 'y' || exit == 'Y' )
    break;
//else again go for input.
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, while the following is valid syntactically, it does not do what you expect:

```
5.919<a<=12.056
```

This is parsed as `(5.919 < a) <= 12.056` and works as follows: `a` is compared to `5.919`, and the result of that comparison (`0` or `1`) is compared to `12.056`. Since both `0` and `1` are less than `12.056`, the overall expression always evaluates to `1`.

To fix, rewrite it as:

```
5.919 < a && a <= 12.056
```

The same goes for all the other similar expressions.

Comment: thanks so much..and can you help me with yes/no. the current input its taking is is 1/ any other number

Answer (score 2):

This line isn't doing what you think.

```
if(5.919<a<=12.056 && 2.340<b<=2.347 && 2.380<c<=2.648)
```

to do what you seem to want, you would need to change it to:

```
if(5.919<a&& a<=12.056 && 2.340<b&& b<=2.347 && 2.380<c&& c<=2.648)
```

same for this line:

```
else if(a<=5.662 && 2.340<b<=2.438 && c<=2.16)
```

that needs to be changed to:

```
else if(a<=5.662 && 2.340<b && b <=2.438 && c<=2.16)
```

When you write this:

```
2.340 <b <= 2.347
```

what C and C++ understand is `(2.30 < b) <= 2.347` and that is always true (1 in C) for all values of b because `(2.30 < b)` is either 0 or 1, which is always less or equal than 2.347. This is arcane and backwards, but it is how C and C++ see the world. I'm sure that this will only bite you once, and this was your turn.

Also, it is bad practice to mix `printf` and `scanf` with `cin` and `cout`, make a choice about how you want to do your I/O and stick to it, mixing them brings other subtle bugs that are difficult to troubleshoot.

For the final part of your question, you can do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void){
    char answer[16];
    printf("Yes or No\n");
    scanf("%s",answer);
    if (strncmp(answer,"Yes",3)==0){
        printf("yes\n");
    }else{
        printf("no\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second part question : 
Change the condition to Y/N instead of 1 and 0. Use character data type, or string or anything similar. And then you can compare the input with "exit".